# This is not a question about the Japanese language

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whatever happened to the close vote reason: "this is not a question about the Japanese language"? Did I just dream that this used to be one of the pre-made reasons for closing a question?

A few times recently I've found myself wanting to apply this, only to find that it's not there. It's one of the most obvious reasons for closing a question. Is there any way we can restore it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a "Default community-specific close reason", which for our site is

> This question does not appear to be about the Japanese language within the scope defined in the [help center](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

However, once a community has their own community-specific close reasons, only they are displayed (together with the migration option, or a custom close reason). There is a maximum of 3 for these community-specific close reasons, and we're already running 3, namely close reasons for

1. translation questions

> Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. See: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

2. typo questions

> This question was caused by a simple spelling mistake, misreading, or typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. For more information, see [our meta discussion on "typo questions"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/).

3. resource questions

> Questions seeking resources or advice about learning Japanese are off-topic here, but you may find our [list of resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) helpful.

I agree that a "this isn't even a question about Japanese" close reason is still quite common (for example we often get questions about Chinese), and I think it would make sense to add this as a fourth standard close reason, but for this to happen we'd have to take this to Meta for a network-wide change, or ask for adding an exception just for our site...

#### How about...

Maybe it makes sense to combine several close reasons into one, for example something like

> This question is beyond the scope of our site, because it might be asking for resources or technical setup, it might be caused by a spelling mistake, or it might simply turn out not to be related to the Japanese language at all. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Since these questions are really just off-topic it could make sense to combine the close reasons, since they don't need to give specific advice on improving the question for reopening.